# Bootstrap-4 navbar dropdown-menu behind content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am experimenting using a Bootstrap-4 theme to build a basic website.
On all pages except ContactUs.php page, the navbar dropdown-menu is behind the content when clicked (when page viewed on a mobile device). 
Would appreciate any advice.
http://i-aminc.com
http://i-aminc.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
Note: still working on Video Ad Stand page so link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you have `navbar` wrap in a `<div>` with fixed height 75px. The reason why the dropdown-menu is behind the content is because of overflow.

2 fixes:

1. If you do need to keep the fixed height 75px, then you need to apply styles to the div that is wrapped the navbar

   ```
   <body>
       <div class="idk">
           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md...">
           ...
       </div>
   </body>

   div.idk {
       height: 75px;
       position: relative;
       overflow-y: visible;
       z-index: 999;
   }
   ```
2. Just get rid of the div!

Comment: Thanks, decided to make the navbar fixed-top again. The reason for the div, the navbar hid content behind it at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bootstrap Studio 4 you can solve the problem of the drop menu hidden by **disabling the option "Truncate" on "Navbar" options,** if you do this the dropdown menu will show up instantly over the content of your website!